# Django Rest Framework angularjs session auth user

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I keep getting this error when accessing request.user from my viewSet class.
***TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'***

Viewset

```
class FriendRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = FriendshipRequest.objects.filter(to_user=request.user)
        print(queryset)
        serializer = FriendRequestSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    queryset = FriendshipRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FriendRequestSerializer
```

it works fine with postman I get authenticated user. but with my angularJs Application I get Internal error.

This is the service:

```
this.getFriendRequests = function () {
        var token = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log('TOKEN IS => ' + token);
        console.log('cookie is : ' + getCookie('csrftoken'));
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFTOKEN'] = getCookie('csrftoken');
        return $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/friendsrq/', {
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'token: ' + token }
        });
    };
```

I use Token authentification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a small typo in your angular code.
Use capital letter **T** in header(That is, it should be **`Token`** instead of `token`)

```
headers: {'Authorization': 'Token: ' + token}
```